# Which generates more heat in a brushless motor winding's: 36V @100% duty cycle or 48V @75% and how significant is it?

Tags: power, brushless-dc-motor, heat

Are the heat losses (in the windings) equivalent for a 36V brushless motor driven by 36V at 100% duty cycle compared to 48V at 75%? While my limited knowledge suggests since the same total power is delivered in either case it should be a white wash (assuming a high enough switching frequency) - my intuition is that the constantly fluctuating voltage of the switching option would create additional heat.

Comment: 48V at 75% is less efficient.

Comment: Thanks, while the overall efficiency is definitely significant those losses are all in the power supply - I'm concerned here only with losses inside the motor (worried about burning out the motor since it will be operating at around it's stall torque)

Comment: @norlesh You asked about the motor, DKN replied about the motor. Your assertion that all those losses are in the PSU is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any resistor, heating is proportional the rms current, not the mean current.

Therefore, even before we start to consider eddy current losses, a 75% duty cycle 48 V waveform will have more losses in the resistance of a motor than a 100% 36 V waveform, even though it has the same mean value (mean voltage = same speed, mean current = same torque).

Once we consider eddy currents in the fabric of the motor, the 48 V waveform will have even higher motor losses.